# XeTeX package fontspec: Use previously defined \newfontfamily with \setmainfont

Tags: fonts, xetex

Because of some problems in Windows with system-installed Linux Libertine/Biolinum Open Type fonts, I decided to define their usage w.r.t. different font shapes in XeLaTeX with the `fontspec` package:

```
\documentclass{artcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\LinuxLibertine[  Path            = fonts/,
                                BoldFont        = LinLibertine_RB.otf,
                                ItalicFont      = LinLibertine_RI.otf,
                                BoldItalicFont  = LinLibertine_RBI.otf,
                                SlantedFont     = LinLibertine_aRL.otf,
                                BoldSlantedFont = LinLibertine_aBL.otf,
                                SmallCapsFont   = LinLibertine_aS.otf,
                                Mapping         = tex-text]{LinLibertine_R.otf}
\setmainfont[                   Path            = fonts/,
                                BoldFont        = LinLibertine_RB.otf,
                                ItalicFont      = LinLibertine_RI.otf,
                                BoldItalicFont  = LinLibertine_RBI.otf,
                                SlantedFont     = LinLibertine_aRL.otf,
                                BoldSlantedFont = LinLibertine_aBL.otf,
                                SmallCapsFont   = LinLibertine_aS.otf,
                                Mapping         = tex-text]{LinLibertine_R.otf}

\begin{document}
Some text here...
\end{document}
```

Is there a possibility to use the previously defined font family in the \setmainfont command, e.g.:

```
\setmainfont{\LinuxLibertine}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: It's hard to understand why this code is necessary and the simple `\setmainfont` doesn't suffice. Could you explain more in your question?

Comment: @egreg: The [Linux Libertine font family](http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=1&L=1) comes with many different styles. In general, XeTeX (or better: fontspec) does recognize them correctly, but sometimes it makes errors. Sadly, this is the case with the LL. Steps to reproduce: Install Vanilla TeXLive 2011 on *nix and put the `.otf` fonts of the LL into `~/.fonts/type1/linuxlibertine/` and the `.ttf` versions into `~/.fonts/type1/truetype/linuxlibertine/`. (cont.)

Comment: Compile with xelatex:

`\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fonspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
regular text, but \emph{italics are to bold}.
\end{document}` So that’s the reason why one want to set up the LL fonts ›by hand‹.

Comment: @saint: While i understand your problem, i don’t know how to avoid this ugly code repetition.

Comment: @Frakturfreund I don't have any issue. Having two different versions (`.otf` and `.ttf`) around can be a source of problems.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late response, I didn't get a notification of comments/answers. I had to define these shapes manually because there were some errors by compiling them with automatic font selection (some text was too bold, italic texts doesn't look correct). So the manual specification of the font shapes solved this issue for me.

Comment: I disagree with the close reason. I came here googling exactly this.

Comment: This is my problem as well. I don't understand why it was closed and not answered.